# Lebesgue measure of closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In Royden's real analysis book(page 42-43), we have the result that

> outer measure of a closed interval on $\mathbb{R}$ is its length.

And to do this we construct an open cover one by one, since exist finite cover the process will terminate. And we get the result.But I have a question that has confused me for a long time.Why finite cover is necessary.In other words why we must need a process that will terminate.

Note that outer measure of a set is defined as

$m^{*}(A)=\inf \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell\left(I_{k}\right) | A \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}\right\}$

Where $I_k$ is non empty open bounded interval on the line.Hence it means outer measure is inf of sum of all length of countable open cover.

Comment: how did you define outer measure?

Comment: Just countable cover version. @Hagen von Eitzen

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3353709/442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since closed intervals $A$ of finite length are compact, any open cover of $A$ admits a finite subcover. So we can restrict our attention to finite covers. It is not necessary to do this, it's just more convenient. In the comments, we developed a guess saying that one could use connectedness instead of compactness to prove this.

Having established that $m^*((a,b)) = \ell((a,b))$, one way to prove that $m^*(A) = \ell(A)$ without using compactness would be as follows. Since the set consisting of the endpoints of $A$ has measure zero (it is countable), removing them from $A$ yields a set of the same measure. Since the set obtained is the interior of $A$ we can conclude by just showing that open intervals have measure equal to their length. (Note that Royden does not prove this first, but I'm sure it can be done somehow.)

Comment: Does this mean we can just use the countable open cover instead of finite cover to prove the result in the same way? But it seems not too much convenience.

Comment: @yi_li Not in same way, no. This is to really to be able to say that the right-most endpoint, $b_N$ in Royden's notation I believe, is further to the right than $b$ is. This is not immediately clear if we do not restrict to finite covers.

Comment: I've never seen the result for open intervals done first (though I haven't looked that hard)

Comment: @yi_li Me neither, just to show you that there are other possibilities ;) Is it now clear to you why Royden restricts to finite covers?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to think in the way that if we can't construct the object in finite steps implies that we can't construct it in this way?

Comment: @yi_li It's not really about constructing an object but rather covering it with open sets. Letting "$n = \infty$" breaks the proof completely, have you tried?

Comment: @ Levi Ryffel Do you mean if $n =  \infty  $ such $b_N$ does not exist,hence no endpoint for the selection ?But why can't we use the endpoint of open cover as the endpoint of the selection, is it because of no endpoint of open cover then?  Thank you I understand it.

Comment: @yi_li Sorry, yes I mean "$N = \infty$". Without using compactness it is hard to see why there is a right-most point. Indeed, we can cover an open interval by infinitely many open sets such that there is no right-most points, e.g., $A = (0,1)$ and
$$I_n = (0, 1-1/n).$$

Comment: I've looked a little more and I'm not sure if one can actually claim "It is not necessary to do this, it's just more convenient." Everywhere I look does $[a,b]$ first, and uses compactness.  Whats the "less convenient" way that works without compactness?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I guess there is none. Here (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Measure_of_Interval_is_Length) they do open intervals first, but it looks a bit sketchy, so I guess it won't satisfy you. But originally I had thought of something along those lines.

Comment: hmmmmmmm. Thanks for finding the link. It is indeed sketchy, because they say that $\sum_i l(I_i)< b-a$ is impossible because $\sum_i l(I_i) < b-a$, i.e. its self evident...! I feel like the implied argument is that you should "line-up" the intervals to see that you don't actually have a cover? But I'm not sure how to "rigourize" that

Comment: @CalvinKhor Maybe one should argue that if there are no overlaps, then there must be holes (maybe using connectedness or something). But I also don't know of any good approach.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect this is the "sketch" of a proof that ultimately will use connectedness. In Tao's Introduction to Measure Theory, he says that in dimension 1, there is a proof (for the lemma: for every interval $I$, $m(I) = l(I)$) with connectedness instead of compactness, but I don't think he goes into depth, and he doesn't say if you can do open intervals first (but they're just as connected as the closed intervals, so I say you have a chance) thanks for the sketch anyway, +1